# RabbitMQ generic and concrete worker

Tags: rabbitmq

I do have a producer, that creates tasks for workers. I need to have

1. Generic worker - that takes care of any task that is put there
2. Specialised worker - that works only on subset of tasks (in order to speed these up)

So so far I tried

1. using direct exchanges -> I can not assign worker to multiple queue names
2. using topic exchanges -> the tasks get duplicated for every worker.

Any ideas, ways around?

Thanks

Note: The priority is not known upon creation of the tasks.

Comment: If your client library allows you to consume from multiple queues create two queues - one for generic tasks and one for high-priority. Than make generic consumers consume from both queues and specialized one - only from high-priority queue.

Comment: @zaq178miami this won't do unfortunatelly. We do not know at the beginning what queues should be prioritized

Comment: Then try to use message priority plugin - https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-priority-queue, maybe having one generic queue and processing important messages first is a nifty solution here.

Comment: the problem is that upon creation of the task, the priority is not known. Basically business comes when the tasks are already scheduled and the want subset of them to be processed faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to address this in your application design, not RMQ topology.  It sounds to me that you need to include a mechanism that tracks job processing status.

When a job becomes known as important,  you would remove the job from the general processing list, and send it to the specialized worker process.